# Что такое "static initialization order fiasco" (SIOF)?

Tags: c++, терминология, c++-faq

Что такое "static initialization order fiasco" (SIOF)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это фейл, который случается, когда переменные с динамической инициализацией используют для своей инициализации другие переменные с динамической инициализацией. В этом примере глобальная переменная `g_b` использует для инициализации значение глобальной переменной `g_f` из другой единицы трасляции, которая может быть, а может и не быть инициализирована к этому моменту, так как порядок динамической инициализации переменных в разных единицах трансляции не определен. На практике может получаться, что код с такой проблемой то работает, а то нет, в зависимости от особенностей компилятора, порядка сборки / линковки.

```
// Foo.hpp
#include <string>

struct foo{ ::std::string value; };

foo & Get_GlobalFoo(void);

// Foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include <string>

static foo g_f{::std::string{"whatever"}};

foo & Get_GlobalFoo(void) { return g_f; }

// Bar.hpp
#include <string>

struct bar{ ::std::string value; };

bar & Get_GlobalBar(void);

// Bar.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"

static bar g_b{Get_GlobalFoo().value};

bar & Get_GlobalBar(void) { return g_b; }

// Main.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << Get_GlobalBar().value << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Защититься от такой проблемы достаточно просто - достаточно никогда не прибегать к динамической инициализации (и заодно и к последующему разрушению). Проще говоря, все статические переменные должны быть `constexpr` и / или тривиально инициализироваться нулями, а также иметь тривиальный деструктор.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86327/discussion-on-answer-by-vtt---static-initialization-order-fiasco-siof).

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на страшное название, вещь это очень простая. Представим, что у нас есть две статических переменных в разных исходных файлах, причем одна из них при инициализации каким-то образом ссылается на другую, например, вызывает метод класса. Поскольку порядок инициализации статических переменных не определен, существует 50%-ая вероятность, что зависимая переменная будет инициализирована первой, и при этом обратится к еще неинициализированной второй переменной. Программа соответственно аварийно завершится, не выполнив ни единого оператора. Вот эта ситуация и называется SIOF.

Поэтому классовые переменные лучше вообще не делать статическими, или хотя бы следить, чтобы таких зависимостей не возникало.

Comment: "Программа соответственно аварийно завершится" а вот и нет, обращение к неинициализированной переменной в общем случае является неопределённым поведением. А со статическими переменными заковырка еще в том, что они инициализируются нулями еще до того, как они инициализируются конкретными рантайм значениями.

Comment: Да, если повезет, то сразу завершится. А если не повезет, то проявится позже каким-нибудь удивительным образом. В любом случае, ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.