# Boost async_read_some serial port

Tags: c++, boost, com-port, asio

Необходимо реализовать простую программу передачи данных по компорту. Устройство которое кидает мне пакет в ответ который я должен прочитать делает это только в ассинхронном режиме. Я пользуюсь бустом и ниже приведу кусок кода:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
io_service io;
serial_port port(io);


void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error,
              std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "all ok" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "byteSize" << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr<<"error: "<< error <<std::endl;
    }
}

void getAnsw()
{
    port.async_read_some(buffer(bufferPack,1),handler);
}

void basicF(uint8_t comand)
{

switch(comand)
{
case 0x24:
{
    read_values_DAC_master *pack = make_read_values_DAC_master(0,21,2,0,1);
    int sizeOfPack = 13 + (int)pack->header.sizeData + 2;
    unsigned char bufferPack[sizeOfPack];
    memcpy(&bufferPack,pack,sizeOfPack);
    port.write_some(buffer(bufferPack,sizeOfPack));
    getAnsw();
    delete pack;
    break;
}

}

}


int main()
{
    port.open(NUMBER_PORT);
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::stop_bits(serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::parity(serial_port_base::parity::none));
    port.set_option(serial_port_base::flow_control(serial_port_base::flow_control::hardware));

    while (stop == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Press Number: \n1 - 0x24 Read values D \n0 - for exit!"<<std::endl;
        int code = 22;
        std::cout << "EDIT: ";
        std::cin>>code;
        switch (code) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            basicF(0x24);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout<< "no such command!"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

где handler это функция

```
void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error,
              std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "all ok" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "byteSize" << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr<<"error: "<< error <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Но мой код не разу не вызывает этот handler. С Чем может быть это связанно?

Comment: 1) это дубликат, 2) это очень далеко от минимального примера

Comment: @VTT дубликат моего вопроса на который никто не ответил?

Comment: да, причем там тоже было далеко от минимального примера

Comment: да, причём крайне не рекомендуется дублировать одни и те же вопросы

Comment: В приведенных кусках ошибок не видно, но в нем `handler` и не должен вызываться. Вам стоит прочитать [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), особенно в части Самодостаточность и Воспроизводимость. А то тут регулярно постят куски, а потом выясняется, что до этих кусков даже не доходит и приложение закрывается без опроса обработчиков и т.п.

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев, [mcve] в идеале — это **целая программа**, которую можно просто скопировать, запустить и получить **точно такой же результат**, как и в вопросе, но из которой **ничего нельзя убрать**, не потеряв остальные свойства.

Comment: Ну вот я исправил может теперь кто нибудь даст хотя бы какой нибудь совет

Answer (score 1):

1. Глобальные переменные `io_service io; serial_port port(io);` чреваты [SIOF / SUOF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912645/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-static-initialization-order-fiasco-siof/912660#912660). Конкретно в этом примере это вряд ли что-то меняет, но тем не менее.
2. В таком виде это не может компилироваться, так как в функции `getAnsw` переменная `bufferPack` не объявлена. (далее предполагаю, что это переменная из `basicF`)
3. Ключевое слово - ассинхронный. При вызове `port.async_read_some(buffer(bufferPack,1),handler);` функция обратного вызова *никогда* не вызывается, даже если операция завершилась сразу. Эта функция только инициализирует асинхронную операцию.
4. Буфер, в который производится асинхронное чтение, должен оставаться валидным до завершения асинхронной операции. А тут он сразу выходит из области видимости. Соответственно выделяйте буфер динамически и удаляйте строго после вызова функции обратного вызова.
5. Теперь собственно как заставить вызоваться `handler`. Для этого надо тыркнуть объект `io_service`, ассоциированный с портом. Например вызвав

```
// не блокирует, надо периодически повторять, пока не вызовется обработчик
auto invoked_handlers_count{io.poll_one()};
```

или

```
// блокирует пока не вызовется обработчик
auto invoked_handlers_count{io.run_one()};
```