# C++ порядок инициализации членов-класса

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

В каком порядке пройдет инициализация членов класса в С++? Сначала будет вызван конструктор класса или сначала будут проиницилазованы члены-класса?

```
class A {}
class B
{ 
public:
   B() = default;

private: 
   A a; 
   static A a0;
   int i;
   static int i0; 
}
```

Comment: Они будут проинициализированы внутри конструктора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала будут инициализированы статические члены класса в порядке их объявления еще до первого создания объекта класса. То есть до вызова конструктора класса.

Что касается не статических членов класса, то будут они инициализированы или нет в контексте вашего примера, зависит от того, как будет создаваться объект класса.

Например, при таком создании объекта

```
B b1;
```

члены класса будут инициализированы по умолчанию, что для класса `B` означает, например, что член класса `i` на самом деле никак не будет инициализирован, так как в определении класса у этого члена отсутствует инициализатор.

Однако при таком объявлении объекта класса `B`

```
B b2 = B();
```

объект класса будет инициализирован по значению, что при наличии конструктора по умолчанию означает инициализацию нулем его скалярных членов класса. Так что в этом случае член класса `i` будет инициализирован 0.

Из стандарта C++ 17 (9.3 Initializers)

> 11 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   (), shall be value-initialized.

и

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means: 
>   (8.2) — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without 
>   a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then 
>   the object is zero-initialized...

Имейте в виду, что при объявлении объекта класса, конструктор вызывается в любом случае, однако тело конструктора получает управление уже после создания членов объекта. Для того, чтобы в теле конструктора иметь дело с уже созданными членами объекта, проинициализированными специальным образом, вы можете использовать список инициализации конструктора.

Например,

```
struct A
{
    A() : i( 10 )
    {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
    }

    int i;
};
```

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я подправил ответ.

Comment: кстати, я даже в формулировке «до первого создания объекта класса» уже тоже не очень уверен... похоже «до первого использования»,  как ни странно, точнее...

Comment: Не понятно, что означает "...при наличии конструктора по умолчанию означает инициализацию нулем его скалярных членов класса." Обнуление будет происходить как раз такие при *отсутствии* пользовательского конструктора или (!) при его *удаленности*, что и сказано в приведенной вами цитате. Удаленный (deleted) конструктор - это уж точно не "наличие". Т.е. все практически наоборот. Также не ясно, что вы имеете в виду под "при объявлении объекта класса, конструктор вызывается в любом случае". Вы ведь только что привели пример с value-initialization, которая выполнятся *без* вызова конструктора.

Comment: @AnT В цитате написано, что если класс не имеет определенный пользователем конструктор или удаленный конструктор по умолчанию, то объект инициализируется нулями. В приведенном автором примере кода класс B не имеет определенный пользователем конструктор или конструктор по умолчанию, который определен как deleted.

Comment: Так я же о том и говорю. В стандарте написано, что необходимое условие: "**не** имеет". **НЕ**. У вас же в тексте: "при **наличии** конструктора по умолчанию". О каком "наличии конструктора по умолчанию" вы ведете речь и при чем оно здесь вообще? Инициализация нулями происходит при **отсутствии** пользовательского конструктора по умолчанию, а не "при наличии конструктора по умолчанию".

Comment: @AnT В классе нет созданного пользователем конструктора по умолчанию, но есть конструктор по умолчанию, созданный компилятором неявно.

Comment: Ну если вы говорите именно о классе, то да, конструктор по умолчанию там будет, ибо это неявно вытекает из других требований (процитированных вами: неудаленность и неопределенность пользователем). Но к чему это тут? Он же все равно не используется.

Comment: @AnT Не понял: где он не используется?

Comment: Я же написал выше: при выполнении value-initialization. Value-initialization не обязательно имеет какое-то отношение к конструктору класса и не обязательно его использует. (Только в том случае, если конструктор окажется non-trivial дополнительно после zero-initialization произойдет еще и вызов конструктора http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.2)

Comment: @AnT Если конструктор по умолчанию отсутствует, то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Конечно (с оговоркой: Только в классах. У `int` нет конструктора по умолчанию, однако он поддерживает value-initialization). Но это не значит, что он будет *использоваться* для выполнения value-initialization. Обнуление в процессе value-initialization делается без участия конструктора. Конструктор в процессе value-initialization вызывается только в том случае, если он не trivial.

Comment: @AnT Я имею в виду создание объекта класса и как в случае отсутствия определенного пользователем конструктора инициализируются его члены.

Answer (score 5):

Из стандарта:

> Инициализация в неделегирующем конструкторе производится в следующем порядке:
>   ■ (13.1) Сначала, и только для конструктора самого производного класса (1.8), инициализируются виртуальные базовые классы в порядке их появления при обходе направленного ациклического графа в направлении «снизу вверх слева направо», где «слева направо» означает очередность появления базовых классов в списке-спецификаторов-баз производного класса.
>   ■ (13.2) Затем инициализируются непосредственные базовые классы в порядке их упоминания в списке-спецификаторов-баз (независимо от порядка mem-инициализаторов).
>   ■ (13.3) Далее инициализируются нестатические данные-члены, в порядке их объявления в описании класса (опять-таки, независимо от порядка mem-инициализаторов).
>   ■ (13.4) Наконец, выполняется составной-оператор тела конструктора.
>   Замечание. Инициализация в порядке объявления обязательна, так как гарантирует разрушение подобъектов базовых классов и членов в порядке, обратном порядку их инициализации.

Т.е. в вашем классе B будет вызван конструктор A, потом - член `a`; `i` был бы проинициализирован после `a` (в порядке объявления), если бы вы указали его инициализатор (или в конструкторе, типа `B():i(5){...}`, или значение по умолчанию типа `int i = 6;`).

Статические члены инициализируются до начала работы с классом, однократно.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*
Если  что не так - надеюсь, гуру в стандарте меня исправят (с использованием правильной терминологии и правильных ссылок на стандарт...)

Answer (score 4):

Если класс инициализируется при помощи конструктора, то инициализацией нестатических членов класса занимается конструктор класса. Поэтому ваш вопрос о том, что произойдет "сначала" не имеет смысла. К тому же ваш класс `B` может инициализироваться в обход конструктора - через value-initialization.

Порядок инициализации неинлайновых статических членов класса зависит от точки их *определения*. Вы не привели определений ваших статических членов вообще, поэтому говорить о порядке их инициализации невозможно. Можно лишь сказать, что эти переменные скорее всего проинициализируются перед первым их использованием (хотя в определенных случаях и с этим могут возникнуть [проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912645/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-static-initialization-order-fiasco-siof/912660)).